# Ionic 3 obtener automáticamente suma de campos inputs

Tags: ionic3

Tengo un formulario con Ionic 3 donde el usuario puede elegir el número de palets que pide de cada artículo. Necesito que se muestre por pantalla la sumatoria de palets y se vaya actualizando conforme cambian los valores. Ahora mismo hace la suma:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero si borro el cero del 20 para dejar un 2, el total aumenta en 2, en vez de bajar 18:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Además, si borro cualquier cantidad, me falla la suma:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La función que suma es esta:

```
sumar(valor) {   
  valor = parseInt(valor);  
  this.totalPalets += valor;
}
```

El template este:

```
<ion-col col-3>
  <ion-item>
    <ion-input formControlName="palets1" type="number" [value]=palets1 (ionChange)="sumar($event.value)"></ion-input>
  </ion-item>
</ion-col>
```

Answer (score 3):

La función sumar, yo lo haría algo así

```
sumar(valor: number) { 

 valor = parseInt(valor);  

  if( isNaN( valor )) return;

  this.totalPalets += valor;
}
```

Ahora, puedes detectar cuando se realice un cambio en tu formulario o bien puedes disparar la función del total cada vez que hay algún cambio en el HTML, o la cantidad